# Nominatim limit and importance

Tags: openstreetmap, geocoding, nominatim

If I limit the results by nominatim will they be ordered by importance? So if I set `?limit=1` will I get the match with the highest importance?

If not, how can I enforce this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the results are always sorted by importance according to [the code](https://github.com/twain47/Nominatim/blob/dd18e740798077f725f6c06e893607f02289d52b/lib/Geocode.php#L1759). Consequently limiting the search to one result will return the address with the highest importance.

Comment: Wow, that source code is overwhelming. Frightening even. But thank you for the answer!

Comment: Feel free to submit patches for improving it :)

Answer (score 0):

Not true for 40 broad st, NY, NY, 10004. doing a limit to 1 result returns lowest importance result which happens to be completely inaccurate. Getting list of results returns accurate important address on top.

Comment: why is this post being voted for deletion? when it is true, you can search for this address in nominatim with limit = 1 and you are presented with wrong result, only if limit = 3 or greater returns result with importance .6 and it is correct result.