# Query limit Nominatim

Tags: openstreetmap, nominatim

I have a **local** Nominatim instance in which I carry out searches within a bounding box. The problem is that for whatever value of `limit`, I get a maximum of 50 results. I understand that this is the limit set by Nominatim so that the public server does not get overloaded.

Consider this reproductible example (sent to the Nominatim public server). Only the server would be different on the local instance.

```
http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=[pub]&format=xml&bounded=1&limit=50&viewbox=4.7718134,45.7073666,4.8983774,45.8082628
```

As I am running my own instance, I am wondering, **is there a way to raise the maximum number of results of my local Nominatim instance?**

A possible solution would be to send queries iteratively, with the `exclude_place_id` argument. For instance, the second query would exclude the `place_id` of the first query and give a list of 50 other pubs, an so on until no further match is found. But this is not very eleguant...

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [the source code](https://github.com/osm-search/Nominatim/blob/dd18e740798077f725f6c06e893607f02289d52b/lib/Geocode.php#L112) linked in [this related post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/122851/198446), it seems this upper limit is hardcoded in `Geocode.php`:

```
function setLimit($iLimit = 10)
    {
        if ($iLimit > 50) $iLimit = 50;
        if ($iLimit < 1) $iLimit = 1;
        $this->iFinalLimit = $iLimit;
        $this->iLimit = $this->iFinalLimit + min($this->iFinalLimit, 10);
    }
```

I was able to just change both hardcoded 50s in `/usr/local/lib/nominatim/lib-php/Geocode.php` Line to 1000 and it worked (returned ~160 results in my case, which is a reasonable for my search).